# How to refresh images of axes of Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, imshow

I want to draw a 3D volume using Matplotlib, slice by slice.
Mouse scroll to change the index. My program is given below:

```
#Mouse scroll event.
def mouse_scroll(event):
fig = event.canvas.figure
  ax = fig.axes[0]
  if event.button == 'down':
    next_slice(ax)
  fig.canvas.draw()

#Next slice func.
def previous_slice(ax):
  volume = ax.volume
  ax.index = (ax.index - 1) % volume.shape[0]
  #ax.imshow(volume[ax.index])
  ax.images[0].set_array(volume[ax.index])
```

Figure is initialized in the main function. like:

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 ax.volume = volume # volume is a 3D data, a 3d np array.
 ax.index = 1
 ax.imshow(volume[ax.index])
 fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', mouse_scroll)
```

Everything worked pretty well even I don't understand what is the `ax.images`. However, problem occurred when I replace the `ax.volume` with a new volume data. It suddenly stop to render! Debug into the code, the `ax.image[0]` is correctly set at each event callback.

But, if change the image set_array method to `ax.show()`. Figure begins to render again. But axes imshow function is really slow comparing to the `ax.images[0].set_array()` method.

How can I fix this problem? really want to use `set_array()` method. Thank you very much.

A simple executable script is attached.
 [plot.py@googledrive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DNZvaHwfCoOpSADmn-WjR5Yz2_T4rCNq)

Comment: It always makes sense to provide a [mcve] such that people can reproduce the undesired behaviour in order to help find a solution. While it might in general not be a good idea to invent custom attributes for existing objects, I'm not sure whether this causes any problems in this case. Appart, the code looks fine. But without a [mcve] one cannot test.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you very much for your advise. I attached a simple executable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work on the same image all the time. Best give this a name

```
img = ax.imshow(volume[ax.index])
```

You can then set the data for it using `set_data`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Mouse scroll event.
def mouse_scroll(event):
    fig = event.canvas.figure
    ax = fig.axes[0]
    if event.button == 'down':
        next_slice(ax)
    fig.canvas.draw()

#Next slice func.
def next_slice(ax):
    volume = ax.volume
    ax.index = (ax.index - 1) % volume.shape[0]
    img.set_array(volume[ax.index])

def mouse_click(event):
    fig = event.canvas.figure
    ax = fig.axes[0]
    volume = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
    ax.volume = volume
    ax.index = (ax.index - 1) % volume.shape[0]              
    img.set_array(volume[ax.index])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    volume = np.random.rand(40, 40, 40)
    ax.volume = volume # volume is a 3D data, a 3d np array.
    ax.index = 1
    img = ax.imshow(volume[ax.index])
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', mouse_scroll)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', mouse_click)
    plt.show()
```